# What frameworks exist to assess piloting skills and ability and how can one assess themselves against these?

Tags: flight-training, pilots, student-pilot

What are the existing frameworks and methodologies used to evaluate and measure piloting proficiency, and how can individuals effectively assess their own skills and knowledge based on these established standards? Furthermore, are there established methodologies for self-assessment that align with these frameworks, enabling pilots to enhance their skills and competence?

Comment: Hello! It looks like this question would be better suited for a forum rather than a Q&A site. https://pilotsofamerica.com is a popular one; although most users are American, users from any country are welcome there.

Comment: Without the meta commentary, this question is only its last paragraph. That paragraph contains two sentences, both of which are too broad for Stack Exchange. Neither is particular to Aviation, either, *"how do you keep getting better at X?"* is broadly about habits and mindsets that aren't related to X itself.

Comment: In 4 words: fly with other pilots.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This is not opinion based, and answerable thanks to the excellent edit by Tedious Tortoise.  https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/acs

Comment: On MS Flight simulator, you get a Grade for landings on landing challenges :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To effectively evaluate and measure piloting proficiency, there are established frameworks and methodologies used in the aviation industry. International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) has developed core Human Factors documentation that outlines the essential competencies for pilots. Many airlines use these competencies as a basis for evaluating their pilots' performance during training, assessments and line checks.

The core competencies established by ICAO are as follows:

1. **Application of Procedures:** Applying the correct procedures during all stages of flight, both in normal and non-normal situations.
2. **Knowledge:** A thorough understanding of aircraft systems, performance, and procedures.
3. **Flight Path Management - Manual Handling**
4. **Flight Path Management - Automatics:** Pilots must also be proficient in handling automated systems and flight management.
5. **Communication**
6. **Teamwork and Leadership**
7. **Problem Solving**
8. **Workload Management:** The distribution and prioritorisation of tasks, procedures and checks.
9. **Situational Awareness:** A clear understanding of the aircraft's position, surroundings, potential threats.

Perhaps with the exception of Flight Path Management - Automatics, the competencies mentioned above are universally relevant for all pilots, encompassing both VFR and IFR flying scenarios, as well as single or multi-pilot operations.

Its is very good practice to consider each of the competencies above as perform a self-assessment. By thoroughly evaluating each area, individuals can identify areas for improvement and recognise their strengths.

I recently had a conversation with the head of training at my airline's training center, and his perspective resonated with me. He emphasized that the best pilots are those who can **confidently and objectively answer the question, "What are your strengths and weaknesses?"** He suggested that they do so by closely examining themselves against the core competencies (listed above), providing detailed and accurate assessments of their performance and areas for growth. This level of self-awareness and alignment with established standards are key elements in becoming an accomplished pilot.

Underlying the core competencies, it is essential that pilots maintain good “Knowledge, Skills and Attitudes” (cf. ICAO’s definition for ‘airmanship’ across much of it’s documentation). These are the driving forces behind improvement, see [Skybrary’s - Competency Based Training article](https://skybrary.aero/sites/default/files/bookshelf/4380.pdf)

Regarding Crew Resource Management (CRM), it is essential not to underestimate its significance. While some CRM training experiences may be uncessarily longwinded, a correct understanding and implementation of CRM are crucial, particularly in multi-pilot operations. CRM promotes effective communication, teamwork, and decision-making, contributing to overall flight safety.

In summary, pilots can effectively assess their skills and knowledge by aligning themselves with the competencies outlined by ICAO, having a good attitude to seek continuous improvement, and engaging in effective self-assessment. Embracing the principles of CRM is also vital to enhance piloting skills and competence, especially in multi-crew environments.

---

*References:*

- ICAO Safety Management Manual (Doc 9859)
- ICAO Manual on the Regulation of Flight Crew Licensing (Doc 9683)
- ICAO Annex 1 - Personnel Licensing